# Find the 8-bit 2's complement for the decimal integer -102

Tags: binary, hex

I need help understanding how 10011010 is the answer for the 8bit 2's complement for the decimal integer -102.

Comment: Have a read of [Two's Complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: My professor did this: 256-102=154, 154-128=26, 26-16=10, 10-8=2. I'm confused on how the 1s and 0s would be filled in according to this.

Comment: I understand that the the 2^7 place would be a 1 because it is a negative number, but I don't understand the other places.

Comment: 10011010 = 10000000 + 10000 + 1000 + 10 = -128 + 16 + 8 + 2 = -102